# The parameter I'm passing through a async function is undefined in the function

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have an async function that on page load it runs a function that gets a JSON file and stores it in songResults. it then gets a random object from the JSON and takes some parameters from it and uses them to set the sources for some elements in my HTML file. I am having an issue with the callback for the event listener, the parameter I am passing through guessingGame() is undefined inside the guessingGame() function and I'm not sure why. any help would be muchly appreciated.

JS code

```
    //A async function to run when the page loads to get the first song and album cover to display.
const onPageLoad = async () => {
  let songResults = await getSongData();
  let randomSong = songResults[Math.floor(Math.random() * songResults.length)];
  audioSound.src = randomSong.song_path;
  audioSound.load();
  albumCover.src = randomSong.photo_path;
  //An event listener for the submit button to run the guessing game function.
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", guessingGame(randomSong.song_path))
};

//async function for when the button is clicked to check the answer in the input box to the json data.
const guessingGame = async (songPath) => {
  //get the value of the input box
  let input = document.getElementById("guessInputBox").value;
  //check if the value of the input box matches the song path in the json data
  if (input) {
    if (input === songPath) {
        alert('correct')
        score++;
        alert("that took " + score + " attempts");
        score = 0;
        changeSong();
    } else {
        alert('incorrect')
        alert(songPath);
        score++;
    };
  };
};
```

What a json file response looks like

```
{
"song_name": "Listen to Us",
"release_date": "1/05/2012",
"album": "Home Brew",
"photo_path": "/pictures/home-brew.jpg",
"song_path": "/songs/homebrewski-listenToUs.mp3"
```

}

Comment: submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => guessingGame(randomSong.song_path))

Answer (score 1):

so the new code updates it kind of it works the first time you guess but the second time you guess it says your incorrect then correct and keeps looping heaps really weird and lags out the browser.

```
const onPageLoad = async () => {
  let songResults = await getSongData();
  let randomSong = songResults[Math.floor(Math.random() * songResults.length)];
  audioSound.src = randomSong.song_path;
  audioSound.load();
  albumCover.src = randomSong.photo_path;
  //An event listener for the submit button to run the guessing game function.
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    guessingGame(randomSong.song_name);
});
};

//async function for when the button is clicked to check the answer in the input box to the json data.
const guessingGame = async (songPath) => {
  //get the value of the input box
  let input = document.getElementById("guessInputBox").value;
  //check if the value of the input box matches the song path in the json data
  if (input) {
    if (input.toLowerCase() === songPath.toLowerCase()) {
        alert('correct')
        score++;
        alert("that took " + score + " attempts");
        score = 0;
        changeSong();
    } else {
        alert('incorrect')
        alert(songPath);
        score++;
    };
  };
};

//need to  change this to an async function once figured out how to store data.
const changeSong = async () => {
  let songResults = await getSongData();
  let randomSong = songResults[Math.floor(Math.random() * songResults.length)];
  audioSound.src = randomSong.song_path;
  audioSound.load();
  albumCover.src = randomSong.photo_path;
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    guessingGame(randomSong.song_name);
  });
};
```

Comment: Please don't post updated-code as an *answer* to your own question. Instead, edit your question to include the updated code (either amending, or replacing the original code).

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated Answer

Thank you for posting more code. It looks like you may have mistakenly passed along the `song_name` instead of the `song_path`:

```js
// From the onPageLoad and changeSong functions
guessingGame(randomSong.song_name);
```

```js
// From the guessingGame function
input.toLowerCase() === songPath.toLowerCase()
```

Another thing to consider is your *click-handler*; you're adding one to the `submitButton` every time a song is loaded. As such, the first time you click the button, a single event handler is called. The second time you click, two are called. The third time, three, etc.

Your submit button behavior really only needs to be set once, and forgotten. It's job is to do one thing: see if the user's selection matches the currently-playing song. And, if the user got the correct answer, load another song:

```js
// Minimal game state
let score = 0;
let songs = [];
let songIndex = -1;

// References to game elements
const submit = document.querySelector("#submit")
const selection = document.querySelector("options"); 

// Begin game functionality
async function onPageLoad () {
    // Load meta data for all songs into `songs`
    songs = await getSongData();
    // TODO: Populate #options based on `songs` data
    setRandomSong();
}

function setRandomSong () {
    songIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * songs.length );
    audioSound.src = songs[ songIndex ].path;
    albumCover.src = songs[ songIndex ].photo;
}

// This will be called whenever a song is changed
audioSound.addEventListener( "load", function audioLoaded () {
    console.log( "Audio has loaded, game can be played." );
});

// We need only a single handler for our guess-button
submit.addEventListener( "click", function guess () {
    // Get our values to compare
    const guess = selection.value;
    const answer = songs[ songIndex ].name;

    // Increment the number of attempts
    score += 1;

    // Check lowercase values for equality
    // If the answer is false, share number of attempts
    if ( guess.toLowerCase() !== answer.toLowerCase() ) {
        alert( `You have guessed ${ score } times.` );
        return;
    }

    // If the answer was correct, reset game state
    alert( `Correct! And after ${ score } guesses.` );
    score = 0;
    setRandomSong();
});
```

Note, this code is untested, but should clearly define a suitable approach to your problem. Please feel free to engage further within the comments as needed.

#### Original Answer

The `addEventListener` method expects a *function* as the second argument. Look closely at your code:

```js
submitButton.addEventListener("click", guessingGame(randomSong.song_path))
```

Note that you're executing `guessingGame`, rather than referencing it. Instead, you'd want to provide another function:

```js
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    guessingGame( randomSong.song_path );
});
```

Now, when the `submitButton` is clicked, our anonymous function will be called, which in turn will pass `randomSong.song_path` to `guessingGame`.

Comment: when adding that the answer doesnt update for the new new song i tried adding the event listener to my changeSong() function but it didnt work.

Comment: @WaxMcgee Please share your updated code.

Comment: i posted new code